# Newcomer's Rhyming Riddle III - What Am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> When adding a letter, I may become boring;
>   When fused with some latex, I help with card storing.
>   With the help of King's clown, I become one who steals;
>   With false fans behind me, in boxes with wheels.
>   My thickness may alter your internet speeds;
>   With a measure of time, I stop that which bleeds.
>   Part of the circle that's loose on the lean;
>   Replacing one vowel, I'm serving the Queen.
>   I sound like a ruling that one is forbidden;
>   Also, in addition, when first letter hidden.

**What am I?**

Comment: By the way, you may want to update your three rhyming riddles with more representative titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> a **band**

When adding a letter, I may become boring;

> b**l**and

When fused with some latex, I help with card storing.

> **rubber** band

With the help of King's clown, I become one who steals;

> band**it**

With false fans behind me, in boxes with wheels.

> band**wagon**

My thickness may alter your internet speeds;

> **broad**band (or, band**width** as OP intended)

With a measure of time, I stop that which bleeds.

> band**age**

Part of the circle that's loose on the lean;

> **waist**band

Replacing one vowel, I'm serving the Queen.

> B**O**nd (007)

I sound like a ruling that one is forbidden;

> "banned"

Also, in addition, when first letter hidden.

> <s>b</s>and

Comment: "My thickness may alter your internet speeds;" referred to band-width, based on the context of the clue, broadband works as well, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You are

> a **band**

When adding a letter, I may become boring;

> bland

When fused with some latex, I help with card storing.

> rubber band

With the help of King's clown, I become one who steals;

> bandit

With false fans behind me, in boxes with wheels.

> bandwagon

My thickness may alter your internet speeds;

> broad band

With a measure of time, I stop that which bleeds.

> band aid -> bandage is better(Rubio)

Part of the circle that's loose on the lean;

> **waistband**(Rubio)

Replacing one vowel, I'm serving the Queen.

> (James) Bond

I sound like a ruling that one is forbidden;

> ban

Also, in addition, when first letter hidden.

> and